# SQL: Combination of one column + count

Tags: sql, count, group-by, teradata

I have a source table containing userIDs and their actions (entries are distinct)

> **userID  | action**
>
> ```
>   1     A
>   1     B
>   2     A
>   3     B
>   3     C
> ```

and I need to get all combinations of two actions together with the number of users who performed both actions.

> **action1| action2 | number of users**
>
> ```
>   A      A      2
>   A      B      1
>  (A      C      0)
>   B      B      2
>   B      C      1
>   C      C      1
> ```

- A-C is in parenthesis, because I don't need rows in the output containing 0 users.
- a row containing twice the same action (A-A) just stores the number of users who performed that action. (user 1 and user 2 performed action A, that's 2 users)

---

I tried to join the source table with itself, but as it contains more than an million of rows, I ran out of spool space:

```
SELECT sT1.action, sT2.action, count(distinct sT1.userID)
FROM sourceTable sT1
JOIN sourceTable sT2 ON (sT1.userID=sT2.userID)
GROUP BY 1,2
HAVING sT1.action <= sT2.action
```

The output itself shouldn't be too big, as the majority of combinations will not exist (0 users performed both actions).
Is there a more efficient way to query what I need?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT sT1.action, sT2.action, count(*)
FROM sourceTable sT1
LEFT INNER JOIN sourceTable sT2 ON (sT1.userID=sT2.userID)
where (st1.RowID <> st1.RowID)
and sT1.action <= sT2.action
GROUP BY st1.action, st2.action
HAVING count(*) > 0
```

The only problematic this is that you need to discard the case where st1 and st2 are matching the same row.In the SQL above I have assumed that the sourceTable has a PK I've called RowID and exclude the case where its joining a row to itself.
I've also changed the HAVING line as that didn't seem to be what your description of the problem called for: it sounded like it was better in the WHERE clause. The new HAVING clause is actually redundant: it should never have a count(*) of 0, but it won't hurt.

Comment: I have no idea if that is going to fix it, but it looks jolly well complex :D

Comment: Thanks for your reply!
I cannot do RowID <> RowID, because I also need the row joined to itself. Using action<=action in the WHERE clause helped a bit, seems this is performing better than doing in in the HAVING section. Apart from this your query seems very similar to mine.

I was hoping for a solution that doesn't use join, but maybe this isn't possible.

Comment: You have to use Join. There isn't a serious query in the world that doesn't - there is nothing at all wrong with Join!